# How to change default resource lifecycle behavior of Terraform?

Tags: terraform

In a Terraform configuration file, we can specify the [create_before_destroy](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/resources.html#create_before_destroy) lifecycle on each individual resource to indicate that during an update, the new resource should be created first before an old resource is deleted.

I would like to make this the default behavior when running Terraform, without having to specify a lifecycle block every time. Is it possible?

Comment: Nope. There's no opposite to that either so even if you could you'd be stuck on things where that's not possible such as a resource that has a unique id that you provide and doesn't allow you to generate a random name (can't think of one off the top of my head now but the old ELB/ALB resources used to be like this before you could specify a name prefix instead of a name).

Comment: I'm fine with keeping in-place update as in-place update. Some types of updates are just changing attributes of a resource and should just be in-place update. However, for replacement update, I'd rather have the behavior of creating new resource first before destroying old one, rather than vice versa. I guess it's not supported, unfortunately.